# Stokes law, falling body problem: what sign?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, drag, viscosity, free-fall

This is quite a basic question, but it gives me just headaches, after I was really thinking about it:

By equilibrium a falling body in a viscous medium will ultimately have the following forces applied on him.

$$F_R = F_G \quad \Rightarrow \quad 6\,\pi\,r\,\eta\,v = m\,g  $$

I know there are others, but let's just focus one these.

Now, this plainly equals $$0 = m\,g-6\,\pi\,r\,\eta\,v\quad\textbf{I}$$

However what's bothering me: in some literature I saw $$0 = -m\,g-6\,\pi\,r\,\eta\,v \quad \textbf{II}$$

How can this be conveyed? I also wonder, in case the body is falling downwards: how can velocity and gravitational acceleration have the same direction?

In my opinion they must have opposite sign in order to fulfill:
$$0 = -m\,g-6\,\pi\,r\,\eta\,v$$

So where's my large error in reasoning here?

Comment: "In some literature" please site the literature too.

Comment: I just found it in German literature. We seem to be notorious for such things:

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fall_mit_Luftwiderstand.

The same convection was made in my exercise without even mentioning where it has been derived from.  Especially because my derivation (I'd say the usual one) seems to contradict it.

Comment: I would just make sense to me, if in the first case $\textbf{I}$: $g$ and $v$ would be both replaced by a positive number, and in the second $\textbf{II}$ only $g$ by a positive number, but $v$ with a negative one.

Comment: @Leon This is why you also make a sketch of the situation. In your case you have the positive z axis directed downwards. This is a bit confusing. You could take upwards as positive z, so $F_g=-mg$. You make no assumptions on the sign of $v$, so just draw that in positive direction. Than you find from your equation that $v=-...$, hence pointing downwards. It is a bit more elegant, since you don't make assumption, or need to think about the direction. It just follows from your sketch and applying Newtons laws.

Comment: Ah, it's about the orientation of the axis! This untangles the mess and answers the question actually.